# Update single cells in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, cell

How can I update a single cell in a DataGrid by row id?

My output works at the moment for one static row. (MessageBox output shows right values)
My intention is to use it all over the whole Grid.

```
private void btnUpdateUserData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("ID: " + mUserDataObject[0].ID + ", Username: " + 
                    mUserDataObject[0].Username + ", Password: " + 
                    mUserDataObject[0].Password + ", Rolle: " + 
                    mUserDataObject[0].Role);
        // to be implemented
        // mUserDataObject[i].Username = "New Username";
}
```

***XAML Code***

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Click="btnUpdateUserData_Click">Update</Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: `btnUpdateUserData_Click` handler is hooked on which button. Individually for each row or at bottom of DataGrid?

Comment: I have added the XAML-Code above. Individually for each row.

Comment: I have added an answer. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update value for row on which button is clicked, get button's **`DataContext`** which will represent an **`instance of User`** object.

Modify the property directly for an instance and it will be reflected in UI instantly provided **`INotifyPropertyChanged`** is implemented on User class.

```
private void btnUpdateUserData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   dataGrid.CommitEdit(); // Add this line so that any editing cell gets commit.
   User currentUser = ((Button)sender).DataContext as User;    
   MessageBox.Show("ID: " + currentUser.ID + ", Username: " + 
                    currentUser.Username + ", Password: " + 
                    currentUser.Password + ", Role: " + 
                    currentUser.Role);   

   currentUser.Username = "New Username";
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

In case want to update property for `SelectedItem`, give `x:Name` to your dataGrid and use it to access selected item of dataGrid.

**`XAML`**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid">
   ....
</DataGrid>
```

**`Code behind`**

```
private void btnUpdateUserData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   dataGrid.CommitEdit(); // Add this line so that any editing cell gets commit.
   User currentUser = dataGrid.SelectedItem as User;
   // currentUser will be null in case SelectedItem is null.
   if(currentUser != null)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("ID: " + currentUser.ID + ", Username: " + 
                       currentUser.Username + ", Password: " + 
                       currentUser.Password + ", Rolle: " + 
                       currentUser.Role);

      currentUser.Username = "New Username";
   }
}
```

Comment: What would you have suggested if I wanted to update at bottom of DataGrid?

Comment: In that case get dataGrid `SelectedItem` which will be User instance. If no item is selected it will return null.

Comment: I have update answer for another approach as well. @user3524628 - Reason for de-selecting an answer?

Comment: I am sorry to say but the issue is not solved completely: I always get the old context data, eg the row containts a username "user" and I edit it to "user1234" and trigger btnUpdateUserData_Click() I am getting "user".

Comment: That's because cell is not committed yet. Any reason you want to have `Update` button? When lost focus is called on cell, it will automatically gets set on UserName.

Comment: You need to call `dataGrid.CommitEdit();` before getting DataContext so that any cell in edit mode gets commit before you access it. `dataGrid` is `x:Name` you have to set on DataGrid in XAML. I have edited the answer to include the details. Hopefully it works for you noew.

Comment: Your last comment on "dataGrid.CommitEdit();" was crucial. Now it works perfect. Great support. Thank you so much!